# Difference between kinematic momentum and conjugated momentum in purely mechanical setup

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, momentum, definition

I don't know much about physics, but I wanted to understand what was the difference between the "kinematic momentum" and the conjugated [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum). As I understand it, kinematic momentum is mass times speed and the conjugated momentum should be the one that verifies the Lagrangian equation (somehow I read it is $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}$). I was looking at [this example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/301345/) to see when they could be different. But is there any simple purely mechanical examples, without charged particles?

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate momentum corresponding to an angular coordinate is not a *linear* momentum but an *angular* momentum. For example, consider the Lagrangian of a particle of mass $m$ moving in a central force field described by the potential $V(r)$ and written in plane polar coordinates: $$L=\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2)-V(r).$$ You can easily verify that the quantity $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{r}}=m\dot{r}$$ is a linear momentum while $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{\theta}}=mr^2\dot{\theta}=mr^2\omega$$ is the angular momentum about the origin.

**Addendum** If $q$ is a generalized coordinate of linear dimension (e.g., the radial coordinate $r$, or cartesian coordinates $x,y,z$ etc), and if the potential is independent of the generalized velocities $\dot{q}$, the generalized velocity corresponding to $q$, defined as $$p_q:=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}}$$ will always be of the form $m\dot{q}$, simply from dimensional analysis.

Comment: But should it always be $m\dot{q}$, where $q$ is the generalized coordinate?

Comment: @roi_saumon Please see the edited answer and let me know whether I should clarify anything more.